# List background color changed and added padding after iOS 14, How Can I Deal With It?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I upgraded my Xcode to 12 and I built my app on iOS 14 emulator device. Automatically added padding and changed background color of all lists in app. How can I fix it ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhXtu.png)

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what’s new in SwiftUI Lists for iOS 14 [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/whats-new-in-swiftui-lists-for-ios-14-e6aed43ca134). Add list style to plain

> .listStyle(PlainListStyle())